# Custom position for center child in forest

Tags: forest

this is my first question on here so I apologize in advance for all the mistakes I'm making, but here is my MWE, essentially:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{forest}for tree={l=2cm}
            [\emph{realisation-rule}
            [MORPHOTACTICS,draw,calign=fixed edge angles,calign secondary angle=0
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[
                    mud & \{\normalfont\textit{agr} \}\\
                    ms & \{ \[\asort{pid}
                    cat & verb\], ...\}\\
                    mph & \< \[pc & $-4$\]\> \]
            \end{avm}}, name= 1, tier=word]
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{\normalfont\textit{agr}\}\\
                    ms & \{ \[\asort{pid}
                    cat & \[\asort{adj}
                    type & B\]\], ...\}\\
                    mph & \<\[pc & $-2$\], \[pc & $-1$\]\>\]
            \end{avm}}, l=7cm]
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{\normalfont\textit{agr}\}\\
                    ms & \{ \[\asort{pid}
                    cat & \[\asort{adj}
                    type & A\]\], ...\}\\
                    mph & \< \[pc & -1\]\>\]
            \end{avm}}, name=2, tier=word]
            ]
            [EXPONENCE,draw
            [QUAL,draw, name=qual
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{ \[\normalfont\textit{agr}\\cl & 7\]\}\\
                    mph & \< ... \[ph & \<\normalfont ca\>\\
                    pc & $-1$ $\vee$ $-2$
                    \] ... \>\]
            \end{avm}}, tier=word]
            [\dots]
            ]
            [CONC,draw, name=conc
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{ \[\normalfont\textit{agr}\\cl & 7\]\}\\
                    mph & \< ... \[ph & \<\normalfont ci\>\\
                    pc & $-1$ $\vee$ $-4$
                    \] ... \>\]
            \end{avm}}, tier=word]
            [\dots]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            \draw (1.north) to (qual.south);
            \draw (2.north) to (conc.south);
        \end{forest}
    }    
    \caption{Nyanja pre-prefixation}\label{fig:Nyanja}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Since the tree is otherwise too wide, the node that has the l=7 option sits  below its siblings to the left and right.
This is why the forest algorithm doesn't see any need to put it centered right below the mother node, which I want, though because right now, its edge intersects the other node.
Also it just doesn't look good.

Maybe this picture of how it looks right now with the intended position drawn in red will explain it a bit better:

[image: critical part of MWE with intended position sketched out]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since your diagram seems to be too wide even when rotated to a landscape orientation, did you already consider rotating the direction of the forst itself, so that ir goes from left to right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I tried to compile your MWE, but I get a lot of "Undefined control sequence" errors. Are you sure it gives you the correct output? I suspect the errors might come from the ``\asort`` command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{avm}% Copied from https://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/tex/avm.sty
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{forest}for tree={l=4cm}
            [\emph{realisation-rule}
            [MORPHOTACTICS,draw,calign=fixed edge angles,calign secondary angle=0,l=3cm
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[
                    mud & \{\normalfont\textit{agr} \}\\
                    ms & \{ \[\asort{pid}
                    cat & verb\], ...\}\\
                    mph & \< \[pc & $-4$\]\> \]
            \end{avm}}, name= 1, tier=word]
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{\normalfont\textit{agr}\}\\
                    ms & \{ \[\asort{pid}
                    cat & \[\asort{adj}
                    type & B\]\], ...\}\\
                    mph & \<\[pc & $-2$\], \[pc & $-1$\]\>\]
            \end{avm}}, l=2cm]
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{\normalfont\textit{agr}\}\\
                    ms & \{ \[\asort{pid}
                    cat & \[\asort{adj}
                    type & A\]\], ...\}\\
                    mph & \< \[pc & -1\]\>\]
            \end{avm}}, name=2, tier=word]
            ]
            [EXPONENCE,draw,l=3.3cm
            [QUAL,draw, name=qual,
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{ \[\normalfont\textit{agr}\\cl & 7\]\}\\
                    mph & \< ... \[ph & \<\normalfont ca\>\\
                    pc & $-1$ $\vee$ $-2$
                    \] ... \>\]
            \end{avm}}, tier=word]
            [\dots]
            ]
            [CONC,draw, name=conc
            [{\begin{avm}
                    \[mud & \{ \[\normalfont\textit{agr}\\cl & 7\]\}\\
                    mph & \< ... \[ph & \<\normalfont ci\>\\
                    pc & $-1$ $\vee$ $-4$
                    \] ... \>\]
            \end{avm}}, tier=word]
            [\dots]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            \draw (1.north) to (qual.south);
            \draw (2.north) to (conc.south);
        \end{forest}
    }    
    \caption{Nyanja pre-prefixation}\label{fig:Nyanja}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But using `\scalebox` is only an ugly workaround. IMHO, a complete redesign using a different type of tree should be considered.